# Adding lines into an existing file

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to write out to values into a file. I get the two values in different `if` statement. How can I modify it to get the two values within the same output text file?

```py
if row == 0 and col == 1:
    print ertek
    with open("Output.txt", "w") as kiiras:
        kiiras.write("data1: %s" % ertek)
        kiiras.write("\n")

if type(pattern_colour) is tuple and row == 2:
    tipus = thecell.value
    tipus = tipus.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    print tipus
    text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
    text_file.write("data2: %s" % tipus)
```

Comment: One method will be to use a variable to store the tipus values and ertek values like a list or dict and then push the content of the variable to the file.

Comment: You can append to a file by using the mode `a`, which stands for append mode: `open("Outputs.txt", "a")`

Comment: Why aren't you using the Hungarian Notation?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a problem with your open mode `w`, you should try to use the mode `a` when opening a file to avoid overwriting,

I link this question as it explains a lot better than I would od [python open built-in function: difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r)

Answer (score 2):

To append the data into a file use a not w. The below code might be helpful

```
open("Output.txt", "a")
```